# Change SVG image color in Android

Tags: android, image, svg, colors

This SVG Icon is loaded from a URL. But this icon is black and I want to change its color.
[image: image link]

Comment: do you directly load the images from URL? which library are you using for this?

Comment: We need more detail.  Are you using a WebView? Glide? Or something else.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-load-svg-from-url-in-android-imageview/amp/

Comment: implementation ‘com.pixplicity.sharp:library:1.1.0’ @PaulLeBeau

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Sharp github repository](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp)?  Right on the first page it links to sample code that appears to demonstrate how to change colours.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm.. the link is broken, but the code is easy to find: https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp/tree/master/sample-imageview